# Multi joins return an exact match, if any

Tags: java, sql

I have 3 tables below (simplified)

```
user |
------
id
name

conversation |
--------------
id
date_created

conversation_user|
------------------
conversation
user
```

I have an `ArrayList` in Java with a list of user that i give to this method :

```
    public Conversation search(ArrayList<User> listUser) throws SQLException, Exception {

// build statement
        Statement st = DataBase.getInstance().createStatement();
        Conversation conversation = null;
        // build and execute query
        ResultSet rs;
        // loop throw the users
        for (User user : listUser) {
            rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT conversation FROM conversation_user WHERE user = " + user.getId());
            // loop throw conversations
            while (rs.next()) {
                int conversationId = rs.getInt("conversation");
                // loop on all user of this conversation
                ResultSet rs2 = st.executeQuery("SELECT user FROM conversation_user WHERE conversation = " + rs.getInt("conversation"));
                // loop on the user list
                boolean matchUser = true;
                int i = 0;
                while (rs2.next()) {
                    // check if there is a match
                    boolean isFound = false;
                    for (User u2 : listUser) {
                        if (rs2.getInt("user") == u2.getId()) {
                            isFound = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!isFound) {
                        matchUser = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                if (!matchUser || listUser.size() != i) {
                    break;
                }
                return new Conversation(conversationId);
            }
        }
        return conversation;

    }
```

I want this method to return me a conversation with the right id if a match exist bewteen the list of users given and the list of user in a conversation.
This should be an exact match (the number of users in the list of user give should match the number of users in a conversation.

If there is no exact match null should be returned as a conversation.

I would like to this the fastest way as possible (minimum number of queries).

What i tried so far is to loop through to each conversation of each user (in the list), and for each check for a an exact match match bewteen the user and the conversation, if i have no exact match i try with the next conversation (loop in a loop) until i find one that i return. And at the end of the iteration of listUser if I didn't find any i return null.
But this is really slow...
I was wondering if it was possible to do this with less queries.

Comment: `// write code here` those are instructions for you, not us. What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried something but with many queries and it's not really effective, i am not really looking for the code but more the idea on how to proceed ;) I can take care of the code

Comment: I have tried to loop through to each conversation of each user, and for each check for a an exact match match bewteen the user and the conversation, if i have no exact match i try with the next conversation (loop in a loop) until i find one that i return if not i return null at then end

Comment: You don't show your java code for executing the query.  are you using JDBC?  Please show ALL the relevant code.  What database platform is this?  What is the max #of elements you can expect in your ArrayList?

Comment: updated, Yes i use JDBC